# How to loop through a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I'm currently working on looping through dictionaries and loops Python. Inside the dictionary is the people who have taken a poll on their favorite language and their results. The Participants list shows the people who must take it; a few have taken while the others have not.

I want loop through the `Participants` list and if they are in the dictionary, it prints that they have completed the poll, print their name, and print their favorite language. If not, it prints that they need to complete the poll followed by their name.

```
Poll = {
'Jen': 'Python',
'James': 'C++',
'John': 'Java',
}

Participants = ['Jade', 'Jen', 'James', 'Josh', 'John']

for Participant in Participants:
    if Participant, Language in Poll.items():
        print("Poll completed, " + Participant + '.' +
        'Favorite language: ' + Language)
    else:
        print('Please complete the poll, ' + Participant)
```

Comment: You haven't told us what problem you have.  "Please help me" is not a Stack Overflow question.  You have an obviously malformed `if` condition; please correct that first.

Comment: @Prune Maybe slightly friendlier? They did say they were new. SO has got a bit of a learning curve we all had to go through

Comment: @h.and.h: Being new isn't a very good excuse IMO either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's bad practice to use uppercase letters to start variable names. These should be changed; e.g. `Participants` should be `participants`.

The problem lies with this line:

```
if participant, language in poll.items():
```

This results in a SyntaxError. You probably mean to check if `poll` has an entry for `participant`, like so:

```
if participant in poll:
    print("Poll completed, " + participant + '.' +
    'Favorite language: ' + poll[participant])
```

The above code will check if `participant` is a valid key in `poll` (in other words, if `poll` contains an entry for the participant). If so, it will list `poll`'s entry for `participant` as the language.

As mentioned in the comments, it's often preferred to use a `try-except` statement in these situations rather than an `if-else` statement (see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/)), like so:

```
try:
    print("Poll completed, " + participant + '.' +
    'Favorite language: ' + poll[participant])
except KeyError:
    print('Please complete the poll, ' + participant)
```

This accomplishes the same thing; if `poll[participant]` does not exist (meaning the participant does not have an entry in `poll`), the `except` statement will be executed, printing that the participant did not complete the poll. The `try` statement will be run otherwise, outputting that the participant did indeed complete the poll.

Comment: A more Pythonic way would be to use `try:{}` and `except KeyError:`.

Comment: Very helpful and easy to understand. Thanks for mentioning the capitalized variables!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what you want: your logic is *almost* correct, but you simply haven't learned how to access dict characteristics ... but you're close.

You cannot compare whether the language is in Poll.items() -- that's something you extract from `Poll`.  You need more practice in how variables work.  Rather, you ask only whether the person is in `Poll`; if so, you extract the language:

```
for Participant in Participants:
    if Participant in Poll:
        print("Poll completed, " + Participant + '.' +
        'Favorite language: ' + Poll[Participant])
    else:
        print('Please complete the poll, ' + Participant)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just have a look at the documentation for dictionarys https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html. Your code can not know what you mean with language. Dictionaries are key/valcue pairs.

```
Poll = {
        'Jen': 'Python',
        'James': 'C++',
        'John': 'Java',
    }

Participants = ['Jade', 'Jen', 'James', 'Josh', 'John']

for Participant in Participants:
    if Participant in Poll:
        print("Poll completed, " + Participant + '.' +
              'Favorite language: ' + Poll[Participant])
    else:
        print('Please complete the poll, ' + Participant)
```